# Which one of the Constraints in Interface builder would only limit the vertical position of frames

Tags: ios

My app utilizes some images, labels and frames that do not need to change dimensions between the 3.5 inch and 4 inch iOS devices. However, they need to change where they are located.

Is there a way to add constraints to such frames to move them by 10, 20, or 30 pix depending on the device?

All of the constraints that I've applied tend to change the sizes of the frames as well.

The way I see it is I need a given button to be 10% from the bottom etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your button to be exactly 10% above the bottom of the screen:

1. Create a Bottom Space to Container (Or Bottom Layout Guide) constraint.
2. Select the constraint you just created.
3. In the First Item field, select the drop down and click "Reverse First And Second Item"
4. Set it's constant to 0.
5. Set the Multiplier to 90% (this will be 10% from the bottom).
6. Done

Per your request, I made a quick video about it: [Percentage Auto Layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOAbTOtudMA)

Comment: can you provide some screenshots. I did what you said above and its ending up resized. If you have the ability, a video recording would be nice. I appreciate your help. Ill play with the above instructions for now and see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Cripto check edit for link to video I made, all for you buddy. First 30 seconds just shows that I created it all from scratch. Next 30 seconds is all the auto layout stuff. Also note that the values I'm putting into interface to initially position and size the button are irrelevant. You can put anything into them, and the layout constraints will still put it in the correct position.